# Log out of Facebook in Ionic app using Firebase

Tags: angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I am using single-sign on with Facebook in my application and have been attempting to logout but have been unsuccessful with the posted solutions. I am currently getting an error stating cannot read property of "logout".  Thanks!

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,$state) {

      var ref = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com");

    $scope.loginFacebook = function(){

      if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){

        $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email"]).then(function(success){

          console.log(success);

          ref.authWithOAuthToken("facebook", success.authResponse.accessToken, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('Firebase login failed!', error);
            } else {
              console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);

               return $state.go('app.gyms');
            }
          });

        }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });        

      }
      else {

        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            console.log("Username:" + authData.facebook.displayName);
            console.log("Profile Image:" + authData.facebook.profileImageURL);
            $scope.displayName = authData.facebook.displayName;
            $scope.profileImageURL = authData.facebook.profileImageURL;
             $scope.modal.hide();
                     $scope.isLoggedIn = function(){
        return true;
      };
      $scope.isLoggedIn();
          }
        });

      }

    };

     $scope.logOut = function() {
         ref.unauth();
          return $state.go('app.gyms');
      };
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for to call `authData.unAuth()`

Let me know if that doesn't help.

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseAuth.js)

Comment: Yes that worked, I need to logout of client side as well. Thanks